# Neighbour Component Analysis implementation in Octave/Matlab

Tags: classification, analysis, projection, mathematical-optimization, nearest-neighbor

I've been trying to implement the [Neighbourhood Component Analysis (NCA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_components_analysis) algorithm in Octave, but apparently there's something wrong with my code and I cannot figure out what it is.

**Note:** I am using Carl Edward Rasmussen's [`minimize`](http://learning.eng.cam.ac.uk/carl/code/minimize/minimize.m) function for maximization of the negative ***f***.

**Note 2:** The test data I am using is the [Wine dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine) available at the UCI Machine Learning repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some external help, I've got the answer to the question. The problem was that I was assuming wrongly that vector product of the difference of datapoints *i* and *j* should be a row vector by column vector instead of the opposite:
[image: gradient]

Comment: So what's your opinion of NCA? I also did an implementation for HeuristicLab and there also added the possibility of using a regularization term which I found in an LNCS article. I did find that NCA sometimes just stretches all points out very far. But the biggest problem is runtime. The gradient calculation is very expensive.

Comment: Yes, completely agree about the downsides. However, I find the algorithm extremely useful (and it actually feels kind of pseudo-cheating) but it is great for visualisation purposes, and also gives some sort of useful information through the resulting linear transformation.